# Issue with left join in sas EG7.1

Tags: sas

I am new to sas and i am facing the following issue. I have two data sets:

1. one set with retailer info, product, date and actual sales
2. the second one has the same retailer info,product,date and some causal variables that may impact the sales

when i try to merge those 2 using a left join (on retailer,date and product) i get all the info i need properly but the actuals column is giving me empty cells. I dont get any errors when its running.

Does anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please share the code you are using and sample of the input and an expected output

Comment: You're doing it wrong somehow. Can't tell you what since you haven't told us what you're doing - ie your actually code. Most likely your join.

Answer (score 1):

after doing some more digging i found out that the issue is not with the join but one step before where i am doing a delta load for the future updates. in the final step of the delta load

```
proc timeseries data=WORK.prep1 (where=(Actuals>0)) out=prep3;
by customer segment;
var Actuals / setmissing=0 accumulate=total;
id Date interval=week format=date9.;
run;
```

it gives me back the date with one day less. So the week 12jul2021 it comes back as 11jul2021. this has as a result the join to have different dates in the 2 tables. for the moment i have put aside this step and it is working but i need to find a solution in order to have it work properly